# Chrome 24 vs IE10 Scrolling Horrible Lag

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer-10

I am currently developing a web application focusing primarily on Chrome 24.01312.57 and IE10. In the former browser, I am experiencing a large amount of lag. However, the latter experiences little to no lag, which is quite opposite to what everyone claims.

To show you the difference, I am recording the screens of my netbook using an iPhone while scrolling down The Chrome Webstore - something Google itself created.

**Testing Equipment**

1. 2 year old Gateway Netbook -Single Core Intel Atom - 1GB RAM - Win7
2. iPhone camera (not that great recording solution, but it is quite easy to spot the difference)
3. Website: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/home (I scrolled down quite a bit for both the browsers before starting the test for those worried of AJAX loaded content slowing down the rendering)

**Results**

1. Google Chrome 24 (No extensions) scrolling down the Webstore:
   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njkRqiNJPIY
2. Internet Explorer (No addons) 10 on the same page:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_E_9OzPers

*Note: Look at the mouse cursor and the scroll thumb - on IE10, the mouse is always on the the thumb whereas Chrome, it is all over the place indicating a high latency between mouse movement and the actual rendering.*

**Bottom Line:**

Before I conclude, do realize that these lags on Google Chrome are **increasingly magnified** as the website becomes more complex and/or the specs go lower. However, IE10 is pushing the FPS quite high even in these conditions. I also did some analysis of the Chrome timeline. In reveals that the FPS drops as you zoom out to the point where rendering takes up to ~900ms per frame (on the Google Webstore) while IE10 is still fluid smooth (and better yet it retains that smoothness on an atom netbook)

1. As web developers, is there some CSS property/ies that is causing Chrome to render the pages with lag?
2. Why is Internet Explorer rendering so quickly?
3. What can be some steps to make Chrome render as quickly as IE10?

PS: Bug Report: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=163092 but no recent developments on this currently.

Comment: That's one of the things about Chrome, it's a heavy beast and very memory hungry. Have you tried running Linux on that Atom? You'll enjoy the performance boost at least moving and loading things in the OS. Win7 + Chrome is killing it with just 1gb of ram.

Comment: I also have a very powerful computer but that seems to still have a lag whereas IE10 is like watching a movie on a 240Hz tv. This test was completed on custom/benching website made to test the performance on each - with a large amount of border-radius and box-shadows. :P

Comment: My first guess would be one (or more!) of the fancy `-webkit` properties is slowing Chrome down, and IE10 is just ignoring it.

Comment: I don't experience any lag at all on my computer and it's not the most powerful, Intel i5 16gb ram, Ubuntu 12.10, Chrome 24.

Comment: Maybe IE makes better use of the crappy integrated graphics for css3 transitions...?

Comment: Oh, also, that page loads more content as you scroll to the bottom.  Are you sure both tests used the same amount of content?  (I'm not sure how you'd ensure that....)

Comment: I scrolled down quite a bit for both the browsers before starting the test.

Comment: Maybe you proved that Chrome loads new content quicker than IE :P

Comment: And, for what it's worth, the page scrolls very well on my MacBook Air, with 433 other tabs open.

Comment: I think this is something you just gonna have to deal with. I mean, Atoms are in extinction anyway, even phones have better processors...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chrome struggles with painting, especially at high resolutions such as 2560x1440 and above. Many websites such as the Chrome Web Store, Facebook, etc. exhibit significant scroll lag on it. IE10 maintains 120 fps on my monitor while scrolling on these sites.

Comment: Count me as the second person on that category.

Comment: So anyone who disagrees with you is a "rabid fanboy"? IE is and always has been one of the worst browsers around - that's why I (and a lot of other people) stopped using it. It's slower than Firefox/Chrome on almost every measure, and its HTML5 compliance is woeful. For a while I went with Firefox, because it was so much better than IE. Eventually I switched to Chrome because of superior native tools for web development. It's not about being a "fanboy". It's about choosing the best tool for the job.

Comment: @xtempore From IE10 onwards and from a purely performance perspective, nothing even remotely comes close to the butter smooth scrolling of IE. It scrolls fluidly at a full 60, 120 or 144 fps if you have a high refresh rate monitor. The touchscreen response of IE11 on a Surface Pro is unmatched even by iPad. Other browsers stutter and lag. As an ignorant end-user I don't care about standards compliance. Developers WILL make their websites work on the OS that has 90%+ market share. Scrolling smoothness is the only factor that matters to users.

Comment: @Locutus: I think you'll find that developers are more interested in targeting the most popular browser (OS is irrelevant) - and that browser is Chrome with twice as many users as IE (and growing). I can't say I've ever considered "scrolling smoothness" as a high priority feature, but seeing as I have the latest versions of IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari I tried them all out on a large web-page. Can't say I noticed any difference whatsoever.

Comment: @Locutus - completely agree!! it's 2015 and chrome still sux in the performance department. I've got an old system (Core 2 Quad 2.4ghz 4gig ram / 1440 x 990 with a low grade graphics card) and chrome is absolutely PATHETIC with lag / FPS / painting whereas Firefox is super smooth (better than IE for me).

Answer (score 2):

I just had and fixed a similar issue.

Apparently Chrome isn't too smart about their recalculation of styles, besides that being terribly slow, so I focused on preventing it from recalculating anything.

I added the 'scrolled' class whenever the scroll event was triggered, but if it was already there, Chrome kept recalculating the new styles anyway. When I modified it to be like:

```
if (!body.hasClass('scrolled')) { body.addClass('scrolled'); }
```

Chrome suddenly experienced a significant speedup (still no IE or FF, but much better than before)

Answer (score -2):

It's the video card on the Netbook! You will experience similar effect on almost everithing that moves on your screen. 
I have a Netbook...

The web you are testing crashed Chrome browser until not long ago...

Comment: how come this "video card" doesn't lag IE10 then?